# How to use "Created by Me" on Custom Object in a Custom Report?

Tags: reporting, custom-object, custom

I've searched here, Trailblazer, and Google and I can't get clarity on the solution.
We have a custom object (ObjectA) and a custom report, and on custom reports there is no default filter for "Created by Me" or the default "Show Me" filter with options: "My Objects" like we have with Accounts.

I simply need a filter on a custom report to see "all ObjectAs created by me (the logged in user)". It can not be by ObjectA owner.

Will Steve's fix work here? https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A7nNMSAZ
and this question is asking about List Views:
[How to Create View For Custom object by having Created By as Logged in user?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/63559/how-to-create-view-for-custom-object-by-having-created-by-as-logged-in-user)

Thanks so much for any help you can provide here!
Hoping Salesforce adds this as a default report as per this idea: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdbHkUAJ/set-default-filter-criteria-on-a-custom-report-type

Comment: Formula field: `$User.Id = CreatedBy.Id`.  A better "solution" is to understand how Salesforce deals with [data security](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/data_security), this includes reports.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! I'll look into it, and thanks for that Formula field!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would adding a filter on "Created By: Full Name" with a relative value of $USER work in your use case?

[image]

Comment: Wow this is so easy, it worked. Thank you SO MUCH! What is the best way to learn more about Salesforce and these not so common tricks with reporting, and code? I wish there was a Salesforce manual, I was trying to read up on Formula Summary Fields and some code written in the forums is not code talked about in Salesforce's documentation.

Thanks again!

Comment: @TonytheDA I usually look at the Salesforce documentation or poke around in a sandbox. If you know the fundamentals of reporting, going hands-on is a great way to learn. Trailhead is also a great resource to learn from!

Comment: Thank you so much! @Wes Lyons